# How to create grandparent foreign key in EFCORE

Tags: entity-framework

I have an employee, with one hourly paying job, each hourly has multiple timecards. I would like the timecards to link to both the employee and Hourly.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Hourly
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<Timecard> Timecards{ get; set; }
}
public class Hourly
{
    public int HourlyId{ get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I specify this relationship in EF.

The code appears to set the employeeID but causes issues with the migration and the Hourly is now set to null.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Timecard>()
            .HasOne<HourlyPC>()
            .WithMany(pc => pc.Timecards)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.EmployeeId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(pc => pc.EmployeeId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Violates [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), meaning duplicated data that can lead to problems such as data anomalies.  One hack would be to include the `Employee` FK in a composite PK for `Job`.  That way, when a `Timecard` has a FK to `Job`, it also has a FK to `Employee`.  Perhaps you could use a job code for a second field for inclusion in the composite `Job` PK or reference another entity, an example of which is below where `Position` is the normalized details of a `Job` w/o employee specific data (e.g. hourly rate) and `Job` relates an `Employee` to a `Position` with the employee-specific details:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public string PositionId { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; set; }

    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
}

public class TimeCard
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public string PositionId { get; set; }

    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Config:

```
// configure Job
// configure relationshipt to Position
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .HasOne(j => j.Position)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired();
// configure relationship to Employee
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .HasOne(j => j.Employee)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired();

// create composite PK using the two FK's
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .HasKey(j => new { j.EmployeeId, j.PositionId });

// configure TimeCard
// configure nav prop to Employee
modelBuilder.Entity<TimeCard>()
    .HasOne(tc => tc.Employee);

// configure relationship with Job
modelBuilder.Entity<TimeCard>()
    .HasOne(tc => tc.Job)
    .WithMany(j => j.TimeCards)
    .HasForeignKey(tc => new { tc.EmployeeId, tc.PositionId })
    .IsRequired();
```

That might need a bit of tweaking but that's the nuts and bolts of it.

Comment: Job plays the same role as Hourly here. You are correct in that timecards should be specific to an employee, and not proxied through the Hourly/Job. I also had issues with migration and had to empty the DB. Thanks.